# getting error while opening model dialog in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to add model dialog in my project.

My html code is like:

```
<div ng-controller="bodyController">
    <!-- This html would live at the path specified in the controller: path/to/your/modal-template.html -->
        <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open Modal</button>

    <div modal="showModal" close="cancel()">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <h4>Modal Dialog</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Example paragraph with some text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="ok()">Okay</button>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

And My app.js is like this:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ui.bootstrap.modal"]);

app.controller("bodyController", function($scope) {

  $scope.open = function() {
    $scope.showModal = true;
  };

  $scope.ok = function() {
    $scope.showModal = false;
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $scope.showModal = false;
  };

});
```

I have added angular UI Bootstrap JS in my index.html file.Still I am not getting model dialog. I am getting an error which i am getting.

My error is like:

[image]

Can anyone suggest me how to do resolve this error.

Comment: update the error shown in question

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: any console error ? post it here

Comment: see my updated ans

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for bootstrap modal. I think the way you are trying to do where you are not using bootstrap classes

There are quite a few issues in your code, so better try the sample and develop as you need

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test">CLick</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="test" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                    </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer below.. This will help you.

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

app.controller("bodyController", function($scope,$uibModal) {

  $scope.open = function() {    

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation:true,
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
      template: `<div modal="showModal" close="cancel()">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <h4>Modal Dialog</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Example paragraph with some text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="ok()">Okay</button>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>`,
    size: 'sm', 
    controller:'modalCtrl',
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
         // return $ctrl.items;
        }
      }
    });
    modalInstance.result
    .then(function (result) {
             console.log('okay');   
   },
   function (result) {
    console.log('cancel');
   });

  }; 

});
app.controller('modalCtrl', function($scope,$uibModalInstance){
 $scope.ok = function() {
 $uibModalInstance.close();
 };
 $scope.cancel = function() {
   $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
  };
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="bodyController">
    <!-- This html would live at the path specified in the controller: path/to/your/modal-template.html -->
        <button style="margin:20px" class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open Modal</button>

    

    </div>
</body>
```